# psql cannot find column in my database table even though the column exists in that table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, psql, pgadmin-4

I have 2 tables in my database. Users and Profiles. Users has the following columns UserID(Primary Key), Email, Phone, Password, AccountVerified and Profiles has the following columns ProfileID(Primary Key), Username, Firstname, Lastname, Gender, Age, Role, ProfilePicture, UserID(Foreign Key). When I make the SQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM "Users" 
INNER JOIN "Profiles" ON "Users.UserID" = "Profiles.UserID";
```

I get the error message:

> column "Users.UserID" does not exist.

So I tried to run the query:

`SELECT "UserID" FROM "Users";`

and it returns the result successfully.

Comment: "Users.UserID" is considered as column name which is not exists ! Remove double quotes to access to the correct column name `UserID`

Comment: Advice: Never use UPPER case in the object names, you never need double quotes around the object names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write `"Users.UserID"`, that is a single identifier in SQL. To use a double quoted schema name, and a double quoted table name, use `"Users"."UserID"`.